# Program broke after changing its process priority?

Tags: cpu, tasks, priority, process

I just want to know how to recover from the changes that I made on a particular program which used to work just fine but after I changed it's priority from normal to high it's no longer working.

To be specific I have uninstalled and reinstalled it several times, changed the priority to normal, also tried to install it on another drive but nothing seems to work! Therefore whenever I try to open or install it my system kind of crashes and the CPU meter goes to high and everything stops! Don't know what to do...

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the priority back to normal while the app is running, which as you discovered can be a real challenge. This will be easier if you start task manager and sort everything by cpu percent descending, to force the app to the top of the list, before running the app in question. Then just be patient for your system to spare enough cpu time to your windows message pump to allow you to do the deed.